# Double Click and Run a Perl Program on a Mac

Tags: macos, perl

I can run a Perl program from the terminal but I would like to run a program by double clicking it on the desktop.

I've tried using Platypus to run the program but the program requires user input and Platypus can't run any program that requires user input. I have right clicked the file and went into Get Info to try to change the program the file opens with. I've also tried to run the command *chmod a-x "filename"* to get the program to run when I double click it but I've had no luck with that either.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your permissions are wrong; you need to set the file to have `+x` (execute permission), not `-x`. Try

```
chmod +x program
```

Once you give it an execute bit, MacOS should give it an icon like this

[image: executable icon]

Then double-clicking it will open and run the script in your default Terminal app. (Usually Terminal.app, but you could also use something like iTerm.)

Comment: Thank you. It's opening in terminal now but it's still not running as a Perl program. I'm getting the error line 1: use: command not found. Do I have to set up something different in the terminal to fix that?

Comment: The first line of your program needs to have a `#!` line - make sure it's something like `#!/usr/bin/perl`